# Как остановить работу уже запущенного php скрипта?

Tags: процесс, php

Есть у меня скрипт, который загружает `(parse)` с `site.com` данные и вставляет (тоже долго) в базу `(mySql)`.

Так вот, предположим, что я нечаянно открыл (запустил) этот скрипт, и сразу же закрыл вкладку браузера (FF).

Понимаю, что скрипт в веб сервере `(apache)` создает процесс, и его руками можно по `pid-`у `kill-`ит.

А можно ли средствами самой php завершить работу другого скрипта?

Посоветуйте люди.

Comment: В аналагичной ситуации, в самом скрипте делал ожидание от stdin определённого набора символов. Если поступали то скрипт запускаеться(через консоль).И раз в ацать повторений скрипт ждал подтверждения.

Comment: А вообще парсить через браузет идиотизм.

Comment: Вызов getmypid() в начале скрипта, с последующим использованием в фоновом "watchdog" не поможет?

Comment: @zenith, насчет запуска скрипта через браузер, да конечно. Но часто(очень - очень) необходимо дать доступ к менеджерам запустить(почему? хм, это долгая история.) скрипт, ну и вот получился самый легкий путь это через браузер, а не консоль(тот же cron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копай в сторону [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Answer (score 2):

Сам погуглил (интересно же как люди решают проблему).
Если парсишь в цикле, то молись, чтобы на стороне сервера стояло ограничение по максимальному времени выполнения (его придумали как раз для таких случаев).
Иначе иди в консоль. Или ребутай сервак.

Comment: насчет time_limit я не переживаю, данные получаю одним махом в виде json

Comment: "Или ребутай сервак" - наверное единственно решение )))(кроме kill-a)

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, а что Вам мешает организовать список таких (потенциально "долгоиграющих") скриптов на сервере и механизм их остановки (тем же kill) ?

Comment: @avp, а можно подробно ? мерси.

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, в общих чертах так:

скрипт в начале своей работы создает в определенном каталоге файл (имя это pid скрипта) cо своим описанием. В конце работы удаляет этот файл. 

Тогда Вы можете (неким скриптом) получить все интересующие Вас pid-ы (с описаниями) и при желании посылать им kill (остановить, убить и т.п.).

Answer (score -4):

Можно просто временно изменить название любой колонки в одной из задействованных таблиц, и скрипт, если конечно не обрабатывает аккуратно исключения, с ошибкой отвалится сам.